# How to configure truffle network with IPC provider?

Tags: truffle, json-rpc, web3-providers, ipc

How can I define in truffle the ipc connection to the node? Currently I am using in truffle.js host/port fields, which are used to create a HttpProvider.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    dev: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration there is a field called `provider`. Using this field an arbitrary web3 connection provider can be injected.

For IPC on Windows it looks like:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var net = require("net");

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    dev: {
      provider: function() {
         return new Web3.providers.IpcProvider("\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc", net);
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Additionally to truffle, you'll have to separately install web3 and net npm packages: `npm -g install web3@0.20.7 net`.